# creating the JSON for options in swift

Tags: ios

I  need to know How to  create JSON will for following data.

I have 5 questions
And for each question i have 5 options.

Options are:-1.Strongly disagree
             2.disagree 
             3.agree
             4.strongly agree
             5.neutral

DATASOURCEMODEL:-

```
class CF_Page2DataSourceModel: NSObject {


    var dataListArray:Array<CF_Page2Model>? = []

    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<CF_Page2Model> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = CF_Page2Model(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }

}

typealias dummyDataSource22 = CF_Page2DataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource22{

    func getJsonDataStored22() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }

}



let jsonArray = [["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

This is my data but i not understanding where the options must added.

```
[
       { "Question": "The waiting period was Reasonable?"},
{ "Question": "The waiting period was Reasonable?"},
{ "Question": "The waiting period was Reasonable?"},
{ "Question": "The waiting period was Reasonable?"}
]
```

So how to create the json for this?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5alHu.png)

Comment: JSON is just Dictionary/Array/String/Numbers (and null). Create it first in Swift/Objective-C, or whatever is your language. Then you'll think about it in JSON.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear.

Comment: @Larme   i have updated my question .please check

Comment: Bridge casts to the same type (`as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`) are redundant and pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Create a struct for the question with members `name` and `option` and an enum for the options

```
struct Question : Codable {
    let name : String
    let option : Option
}

enum Option : String, Codable {
    case stronglyDisagree = "strongly disagree", disagree
    case agree, stronglyAgree  = "strongly agree", neutral
}
```

Rather than an array of dictionaries create the array with `Question` instances

```
let questions = [Question(name: "The waiting period was Reasonable?", option: .neutral),
                 Question(name: "The waiting period was Reasonable?", option: .stronglyDisagree),
                 Question(name: "The waiting period was Reasonable?", option: .neutral),
                 Question(name: "The waiting period was Reasonable?", option: .agree),
                 Question(name: "The waiting period was Reasonable?", option: .neutral)]
```

Thanks to the `Codable` protocol it's very easy to create the JSON

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(questions)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch { print(error) }

// [{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"neutral"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"strongly disagree"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"neutral"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"agree"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"neutral"}]
```

---

In case you need all options separately – I recommend not to include all options in each question – create an umbrella struct

```
struct QuestionData  : Codable {
    let questions : [Question]
    let options : [Option] = [.stronglyDisagree, .disagree, .agree, .stronglyAgree, .neutral]
}
```

and encode

```
let questionData = QuestionData(questions: questions)

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(questionData)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch { print(error) }

// {"options":["strongly disagree","disagree","agree","strongly agree","neutral"],"questions":[{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"neutral"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"strongly disagree"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"neutral"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"agree"},{"name":"The waiting period was Reasonable?","option":"neutral"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to updated question, using struct that conforms to the Swift `Codable` protocol.

```
struct Quiz: Encodable {
    let question: String
    let options: [Int : String]
}
```

If your `getJsonDataStored22` function have all questions, you can make it return an array of `[Quiz]` as JSON encoded `Data`, like so:

```
func getJsonDataStored22() throws -> Data {
    let question1 = Quiz(question: "The waiting period was Reasonable?",
                         options: [1: "Strongly Disagree", 2: "Disagree", 3: "Agree", 4: "Strongly Agree", 5: "Neutral"])
    let question2 = Quiz(question: "The waiting period was Reasonable?",
                         options: [1: "Strongly Disagree", 2: "Disagree", 3: "Agree", 4: "Strongly Agree", 5: "Neutral"])

    // let question3 and so on...

    return try JSONEncoder().encode([question1, question2])
}
```

**Usage-1** if-statement

```
if let jsonData = try? getJsonDataStored22() {
    print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

**Usage-2** do-catch

```
do {
    let jsonData = try getJsonDataStored22()
    print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Output**:

```
[  
   {  
      "question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?",
      "options":{  
         "3":"Agree",
         "1":"Strongly Disagree",
         "4":"Strongly Agree",
         "2":"Disagree",
         "5":"Neutral"
      }
   },
   {  
      "question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?",
      "options":{  
         "3":"Agree",
         "1":"Strongly Disagree",
         "4":"Strongly Agree",
         "2":"Disagree",
         "5":"Neutral"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: i have updated my question .please check .how to solve it

Comment: what should give in Array<Dictionary<String,String>> according here

Comment: According to the name of the method `getJsonDataStored`, I would suggest this method should return `Data`, see my update answer if that would be of any help

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON like given below

```
{
  "Array": [
    {
      "Question": "The waiting period was Reasonable?",
      "selectedOption": {
        "Strongly disagree": 0,
        "disagree": 1,
        "agree": 0,
        "stronglyAgree": 0,
        "neutral": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Its array of dictionary and each dictionary contains the question and its options dictionary, selected option value will be 1 rest are 0. Hope it help.

Comment: Here how to give in  let jsonArray = [["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

Comment: what you want its not clear from where you get this [["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"],["Question":"The waiting period was Reasonable?"]] data ?

Comment: this is dummy data